# How to set Dragonfly for use with S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, dragonfly-gem

In my `initializers/dragonfly.rb` I put this:

```
require 'dragonfly/rails/images'

app = Dragonfly[:app_name]
app.datastore = Dragonfly::DataStorage::S3DataStore.new({
  :bucket_name        => 'bucket_name',
  :access_key_id      => 'key...',
  :secret_access_key  => 'key...'
})
```

But doesn't work, app still saving files in local. What I missing?

EDIT: I changed `Dragonfly[:app_name]` to `Dragonfly[:images]` and it works. Why I need to set `:images`, if I can upload any type of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the 'dragonfly/rails/images' default settings, it sets Dragonfly[:images] as the app name. See the Dragonfly [documentation](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Rails3.html) for how you customize it inside of config/initializers/dragonfly.rb. You could do something like this:

```
  require 'dragonfly'

  app = Dragonfly[:app_name]
  app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
  app.configure_with(:rails)

  # ... etc
```